# how to solve fcm notification response receive failure issue?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

I faced a problem using flutter. fcm notification test time console side successful but app side showing below image

```
   D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(31732): broadcast received for message
D/FA      (31732): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
D/FA      (31732): Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem in the integration of Firebase Messaging rather it is related to Firebase Analytics, if it is not integrated with your app, then you would see this line in the logs:

```
Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
```

You can ignore it, or just add the package [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics) package to your app  by the following command without any required integration steps:

```
flutter pub add firebase_analytics
```

Comment: thanks. please send any good example link. i need to implement app side fcm notification. fcm console configuration completed already . my first flutter project. please help me

Comment: Just add the `firebase_messaging` package with the command `flutter pub add firebase_messaging`  in the projects folder and start sending the notifications from the Firebase Console while the app is terminated or in background in you will see it working as a charm. If it helped you then I would be glad if you accepted the answer and I would be glad for if you have any further questions.

Comment: Here is the official docs for the integration of Firebase Cloud Messaging with Flutter, just follow the steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client

Comment: thanks @moaz . now notification working but notification click time particular page calling relate listener not working FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async { }. i will try.  thanks for your help

Comment: Just add `await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()` before it and it will work.